# error in implementing Ignite.net with persistence

Tags: c#, .net-core, ignite, persistent-storage

I'm new in Ignite.net technology and trying to implement it with data persistence feature (using EF core 2.1 for my cache store classes).
I configure Ignite Configuration in this way

```
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            JvmDllPath = @"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll",
            IsActiveOnStart = true,
            ClientMode = false,
            IgniteInstanceName = FirstValues.IgniteInstanceName,
            WorkDirectory = @"C:\IGNITE_HOME\workspace",
            GridName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            DataStorageConfiguration = new DataStorageConfiguration()
            {
                DefaultDataRegionConfiguration = new DataRegionConfiguration()
                {
                    PersistenceEnabled = true,
                    Name = "inMemoryRegion",
                    CheckpointPageBufferSize = 1024,
                },
                WriteThrottlingEnabled = true
            },
            BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration()
            {
                CompactFooter = true,
                KeepDeserialized = false
            }
        };

        cfg = FirstValues.cacheConfigAll(cfg);
        cfg = FirstValues.setupDiscoveryConfig(cfg);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE", "true");
        var ignite = Ignition.TryGetIgnite() ?? Ignition.Start(cfg);
        ignite.SetActive(true);
        var s = ignite.GetCluster().ForServers().GetNodes();
        ignite.GetCluster().SetBaselineTopology(s);
```

these two classes implemented in this way

```
        public static IgniteConfiguration cacheConfigAll(IgniteConfiguration config)
    {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfigVehicle = VehicleCacheCfgReader();

        CacheConfiguration cacheConfigDevice = DeviceCacheCfgReader();

        CacheConfiguration cacheConfigZone = ZoneCacheCfgReader();

        CacheConfiguration cacheConfigGeoPoint = GeoPointCacheCfgReader();

        List<CacheConfiguration> list = new List<CacheConfiguration>();
        list.Add(cacheConfigVehicle);
        list.Add(cacheConfigDevice);
        list.Add(cacheConfigZone);
        list.Add(cacheConfigGeoPoint);
        config.CacheConfiguration = list;
        return config;
    }

    public static IgniteConfiguration setupDiscoveryConfig(IgniteConfiguration config)
    {
        TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        var ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ((TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder)ipFinder).MulticastGroup = "228.10.10.157";
        ipFinder.LocalAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        spi.IpFinder = ipFinder;
        config.DiscoverySpi = spi;
        return config;
    }
```

and here it is one of my cache stores (All of them are similar to each other)

```
        public static CacheConfiguration VehicleCacheCfgReader()
    {
        return new CacheConfiguration(FmsCacheName)
        {
            Name = VehicleCacheName,
            SqlSchema = "PUBLIC",
            Backups = 1,
            CacheMode = CacheMode.Partitioned,
            WriteSynchronizationMode = CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FullSync,
            AtomicityMode = CacheAtomicityMode.Atomic,
            WriteBehindEnabled = true,
            CacheStoreFactory = new VehicleCacheStoreFactory(),
            ReadThrough = true,
            WriteThrough = true,
            KeepBinaryInStore = false,
            DataRegionName = "inMemoryRegion",                
            QueryEntities = new List<QueryEntity>()
            {
                new QueryEntity()
                {
                    TableName = VehicleCacheName,
                    KeyType = typeof(string),
                    KeyFieldName = "Id",
                    ValueType = typeof(Vehicle),
                    Fields = new List<QueryField>() {
                            new QueryField("Id", typeof(string)) { IsKeyField = true },
                            new QueryField("Name", typeof(string)),
                            new QueryField("ZoneId", typeof(string))
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

and now  when i'm starting my ignite I have this error

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: An error occurred during cache configuration loading from file [file=C:\IGNITE_HOME\workspace\db\node00-f9d2cd52-ad3e-4304-92ce-92f6585cb0a6\cache-DeviceCache1212201883355PM\cache_data.dat]
at org.

apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1025)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractBootstrap.start(PlatformAbstractBootstrap.java:48)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformIgnition.start(PlatformIgnition.java:75)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: An error occurred during cache configuration loading from file [file=C:\IGNITE_HOME\workspace\db\node00-f9d2cd52-ad3e-4304-92ce-92f6585cb0a6\cache-DeviceCache1212201883355PM\cache_data.dat]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.FilePageStoreManager.readCacheData(FilePageStoreManager.java:843)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.FilePageStoreManager.readCacheConfigurations(FilePageStoreManager.java:785)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.addCacheOnJoinFromConfig(GridCacheProcessor.java:888)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCachesOnStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:753)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onReadyForRead(GridCacheProcessor.java:737)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.notifyMetastorageReadyForRead(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:396)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readMetastore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:662)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.notifyMetaStorageSubscribersOnReadyForRead(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:4610)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1048)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractBootstrap.start(PlatformAbstractBootstrap.java:43)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@14514713
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:147)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.FilePageStoreManager.readCacheData(FilePageStoreManager.java:839)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ignite instance name thread local must be set or this method should be accessed under org.apache.ignite.thread.IgniteThread
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.localIgnite(IgnitionEx.java:1411)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.threadLocalContext(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:398)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.readExternal(BinaryObjectImpl.java:695)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2085)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:139)
```

Comment: What is your topology, i.e., what other nodes are present when you start this one?

Comment: As I said I'm new in this kind of techs
Actually I do not any thing about topologies in ignite
thus I do not set any config for that reason.
should I do that?

Comment: Do you have any other Ignite nodes other than this one? Can you create a small reproducer project, share it via zip or github?

Comment: Now I do not have any other node
How could I send project to you?
Gmail?

Comment: Upload it somewhere, post a link in your question.

Comment: I Don't know why but when I changed client mode to true nothing happened(any error or next line)

Comment: If you don't have server nodes running client mode would not work.

Comment: Here it is. 
Thanks for your help
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19WYnEUZvOlKw0j1JySQFIvblqRijMmPE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: excuse me @alamar , can you find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous guess was wrong, as it seems.

There is an issue [IGNITE-10451](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-10451), I'm afraid it will mean you will not be able to use Cache Store together with Persistence when using Ignite.Net.

If you remove CacheStore definition on all caches and remove work dir, it will start without errors.

Comment: Is there any way to persistence data without cache store?
As I read Ignite life cycle needs cache stores to save data, without it we just have cache on memory

Comment: Native Persistence will save data on disk, restore it after restart.

Comment: Do you have any sample code  or tutorial for that?
I should complete my task until tomorrow, i am in a hurry

Answer (score 0):

After some search I've decided to implement cache store  mechanism by myself.
As you can see In Ignite architecture we should access to  storage database when we do not have data on cache, thus I write some codes in my get functions to read data and write them on cache when its cache does not have asked data.